# Not able to store data in localstorage in ionic ios

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am working on ionic project and wants to keep logged in after close the app by storing data in local storage.

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
```

For storing

```
this.storage.setItem('userdata', data['data'])
        .then(
            () => {
                this.getStorageData();
            },
            error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
          );
    enter code here
```

For getting

```
return this.storage.getItem('userdata').then(
      data => {

           return data;
      },
      error => {

      }
    );
```

The same code is working in Android but not in IOS

Answer (score 0):

Use async await to use with return statement

Case : 1

```js
async getData(){
    await return this.storage.getItem('userdata').then(
        data => {

           return data;
        },
        error => {

        }
    );
}
```

Case : 2

```js
getData(){
    return this.storage.getItem('userdata').then(
        data => {

            this.callMyFunctionToUseValue(data)
        },
        error => {

        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up NATIVE STORAGE syntax.set

wrong:

```
     this.storage.setItem('userdata', data['data'])
    .then(
        () => {
            this.getStorageData();
        },
        error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
      );
```

correct:

```
     this.storage.setItem('userdata',{var1: data['data']})
    .then(
        () => {
            this.getStorageData();
        },
        error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
      );
```

get
wrong:

```
  return this.storage.getItem('userdata').then(
  data => {

       return data;
  },
  error => {

  }
);
```

correct:

```
   return this.storage.getItem('userdata').then(
  data => {

       return data.var1;
  },
  error => {

  }
);
```

Your code you are directly assigning userdata to some data. For correct way please use a sub variable assigning value to whatever.